# How to switch perspective in eclipse via command line?

Tags: eclipse, command-line, switch-statement, perspective

Can anyone help me with the command line option to switch perspective in eclipse, while the workspace is open. I already tried the command “eclipse.exe -perspective com.prqa.ui.perspective”, but it opens a new instance, I would want to shift to a new perspective in the same instance of eclipse.

Here, PRQA perspective is a perspective created due to external eclipse plugin "Helix QAC".

Otherwise, is there any key and value pair which i can use in, eclipse launch configurations, which can open my required perspective, when i run the launch file?

Thanks

Comment: Opening a file is the only thing you can do in an open workspace from the command line. Everything else will start a new instance.

Comment: Hi Greg, is there a key value pair which i could perhaps use in my launch file ?
Like <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui/PerspectiveId" value="com.prqa.ui.perspective"/>

Comment: A launch will start a new instance